# Using python,selenium,chrome-driver take all page source not only class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"url_path_of_my_location\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("url_of_my_website")
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mk-league-product-name")
for x in posts:
  print(x.text)
```

It works good, but can I somehow print all source code of the page, not only this elements by class name
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2630' in position 32626: character maps to <undefined>